# Show GameObject in the center of screen in runtime by using AR Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I position GameObject in the center of screen at runtime. My current GameObject is positioned on the left side of the screen and I want it to be positioned in the middle of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Don't ask a question with one line of sentence. Try to explain what you tried and what didn't work next time.

Answer (score 0):

Get the center position of the screen with `Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint`. Pass in `0.5` to the `x` and `y` axis of the this function. Use `Camera.nearClipPlane +yourCustomOffset` for the `z` axis to make sure that the GameObject will be positioned where it can actually be seen.

```
void centerGameObject(GameObject gameOBJToCenter, Camera cameraToCenterOBjectTo, float zOffset = 2.6f)
{
    gameOBJToCenter.transform.position = cameraToCenterOBjectTo.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, cameraToCenterOBjectTo.nearClipPlane + zOffset));
}
```

Then you can call it with

```
centerGameObject(yourGameObject, Camera.main);
```

The default `zOffset`(2.5f) should work but you can change it by supplying the third parameter.

```
centerGameObject(yourGameObject, Camera.main, 5f);
```